# Retag request - merge [envoyproxy] into [envoy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are [75](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoy) and [72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy) questions each and there doesn't seem to be any difference between them.

The project is called Envoy but its website is at https://www.envoyproxy.io/ which may be causing the confusion. I'm proposing that we merge [envoyproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy) into [envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoy) and then set [envoyproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy) to be a synonym.

Comment: Also 10 questions are tagged with both tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoy+envoyproxy

Comment: One problem: there exists [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/envoy), which appears to be a PHP framework. [[tag:envoy]] may not be sufficient disambiguation.

Comment: There is already a [laravel-envoy] tag. 20 of the 75 [envoy] entries match a search for "[envoy] laravel" and 4 of those already have the [laravel-envoy] tag. If I manually edit the other 16 to add [laravel-envoy] and remove [envoy], would that help to get approval for this merger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoy) tag needed a lot of disambiguation. It had questions related to:

- Laravel-Envoy - which had to use [laravel-envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-envoy) instead (8)
- Python envoy library - which had to use [python-envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-envoy) instead (8)
- Envoy Proxy - which had to use [envoyproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy) instead (59)

As there were only 75 questions in the tag, I manually went through all of them and retagged them correctly. Now for the [envoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoy) tag, since most of questions were related to envoyproxy, it makes sense to merge it and synonymize with [envoyproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy). The merge is also now complete.

Comment: Thank you for resolving so thoroughly.