# Confusion between [helm] and [kubernetes-helm]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag wiki for [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) assures us it has to do with the [Emacs incremental completion and selection narrowing framework](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/), specifically pointing out:

> This tag is not for Kubernetes Helm - it is instead the tag [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm).

[kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) is indeed a tag about [the package manager for Kubernetes](https://helm.sh/).

Not surprisingly, tag usage does not quite match these descriptions. Searching for [[helm] emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhelm%5D+emacs) yields right now 158 results, versus the 467 posts for [[helm] kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhelm%5D+kubernetes). That itself is not great but not unheard of either. The surprising part is that [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) has actually an sponsorship from the Kubernetes package manager (judging by the icon).

I'm not sure what is the right action here. I suppose the sponsorship should be associated with the correct tag [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm), which is much more popular anyway. At the same time, it does seem that [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) is more widely understood as the package manager than the Emacs framework. Maybe it would make sense to:

1. Move the sponsorship from [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) to [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm).
2. Rename [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) to [emacs-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-helm).
3. Either leave [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) deleted or make it a synonym for [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm).

This would still leave plenty of mistagged questions under the new [emacs-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-helm), though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We just encountered a similar [issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380909/retag-request-merge-envoyproxy-into-envoy/381014#381014) with [envoyproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/envoyproxy).

Could we please:

1. Move the sponsorship from [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) to [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm)
2. Change the tag of the 158 results of for [[helm] emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhelm%5D+emacs) from [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) to [emacs-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-helm)
3. Merge the remaining [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) items into [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm)
4. Make [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) an alias for [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm)

Comment: At a high level view this does seem the correct way. However, unlike [envoyproxy], this is something that involves tag sponsorships, something which as a moderator, I cannot do. This needs intervention by the community manager team, and the devs. I will talk to them about this.

Comment: Also in this case, there are a lot more questions related to emacs, unlike envoy. We also have to talk to someone from the emacs tag just to make sure that they're on the same page.

Comment: #1 is done. The sponsorship has been moved from [tag:helm] to [tag:kubernetes-helm]

Comment: Thanks, I've pinged a CM to do #2 for now, as they can do it without any disruption.

Comment: Ok, I've done #2 through #4

Comment: ... and I did the 5th, which is to add the [status-completed] :p ... Thanks @shog!