# Disambiguate the [rook] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

This question is prompted by the tag edit that came up in the review queue. The edit suggested to completely overwrite the tag wiki for [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) without preserving the original content. I rejected the edit.

[rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) has been used originally for questions about the R package Rook (26 questions on [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook)+[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)). Lately it is being used mostly for the Kubernetes storage orchestrator (8 questions on [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook)+[kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes)). It seems to have become sponsored by the company behind Rook.

What's the best approach here? Rename the [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) tag to [rook-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook-package), retagging the R-related questions, and leave [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) for use by Kube-related questions?

Comment: Tag renames are possible, yes.

Comment: Note that the tag is also being sponsored.

Comment: @JoshLee sponsored by the wrong people, looks like.

Comment: Sigh, don't the kubernetes people check the tag before requesting for sponsorship? They did the same with [helm] (which was an emacs tag).

Comment: @BhargavRao: What are the odds that some _other project_ is using a four-letter English word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented yesterday night, the *same* situation happened before with [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm), [Confusion between [helm] and [kubernetes-helm]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381337/4099593). Fortunately for us, this tag has 40 posts and we don't need to struggle a lot. My proposal would be to

1. Retag the 8 questions that also have the [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) tag to [kubernetes-rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-rook). https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brook%5D+%5Bkubernetes%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0. This needs to be done manually.
2. Rename [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) to [rook-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook-package) or [r-rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-rook). This would preserve the present tag wiki. (I've not checked if it is plagiarized or not).
3. Transfer the sponsorship from [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rook) to [kubernetes-rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-rook). We either need a CM to do this here from SO end, or catch Dan Kohn, who spearheaded the helm transfer, to do this from the kubernetes end.
4. Reapply that suggested edit to the newer tag, [kubernetes-rook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-rook).

Comment: I can do 1 and 4, who would be able to do 2 and 3? Any mod? SE people?

Comment: I can do 2, but we need to contact a CM for 3. I'll try to poke around tomo morning as soon as I get up.

Comment: I added the "kubernetes-rook" tag to the relevant questions and entered the (previously rejected) edit into its wiki. I referenced "r-rook" as the alternative in the usage guidance.

Comment: I poked a CM, and they informed me that they will look into this. Once they check it, I'll proceed with the other steps.